# get value from sessionStorage in Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, session, laravel-5.1

I am storing `user_id` value in `sessionStorage` using javascript as

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user_id',id);
```

I want to pull this value form sessionStorage in php file, How I can do it. I used php `$_SESSION` super global but it returns an error. I used laravel's built in session function but it rather stores/retrieves values from i do not know where but not from `session storage`.

Comment: There's a function for session's in laravel-5.1

Comment: @aldrin27 I don't think laravel session is storing/retrieving the values in session storage as I said in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No can do...

`sessionStorage` is client side, and stored on the users machine. PHP is server side. PHP can not access anything on the client computer (luckily). You'll have to explicitly send that `user_id` along with you request (trough GET or POST variables ie).

Perhaps the easiest way here would be to store that `user_id` as a **cookie**. That way it gets send along with every request, and can be accessed both by javascript and php.

Comment: I want to send the data without submitting the form.